# Getting error "mat-nav-list is not a known element"

Tags: angular, angular-material

Getting error "mat-nav-list is not a known element" , used @angular/material" version "^5.2.5"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 89):

None of above worked for me.  I had to include 'MatListModule' and it worked.

Comment: what is the import for that?

Comment: `import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';` See https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

Comment: According to the documentation also it's `MatListModule` but for some reason it's still not working for me. I have imported and exported it from a custom module just for Material modules.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure that the component is loading well in the browser, without any imports yet.
2. Now follow the implementation as per Docs presented on https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

If you're confused by the documentation, here's what you should do -

Head to the module of the component and add the following

```js
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
```

and

```js
imports: [
   // Other imports
   MatSidenavModule
],
```

Then you can write the HTML code. The Nav should work well.

That's it!

Please let me know if the error persists

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have imported MatListModule and declared it in your imports in the App.Component module. It works for me

Answer (score 6):

In order to overcome the error

```
<mat-nav-list>
```

tag is not known as an element, we need to import
MatListModule along with MatSidenavModule as

```
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
```

Comment: adding {MatListModule} solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It may still help someone
I forgot to declare the Component where I use the 'mat-nav-list' in the app-module

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the component you want if you are using standalone component!

```
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
```