# Angular Matirial icon is not working Angular latest version

Tags: angular

i just install angular new version and and install Angular Material library. when i import the icon i got the error was

slidebar.component.html

```
'mat-list-item' is not a known element:
```

this is the code i have written

```
<mat-list-item [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
         <mat-icon color="primary" mat-list-icon> directions_car </mat-icon>
             <a routerLink="/car">Cars</a>
     </mat-list-item>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list'


 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';

Comment: MatListModule  i add this but same error

Comment: wait i will share my github link you can easy to correct

Comment: kindly check it here : https://github.com/kobin11/angular-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `MatListModule` into your app.module.ts and provide it in the imports array like below:

```
    import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
    
    
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [ MatListModule ], //Add here
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Instead vote for https://stackoverflow.com/q/49926771/5468463

Comment: i have update above my app.module.ts can you check it

Comment: angular latest verision also i got the error github.com/kobin11/angular-project  check here

Comment: Look good now. Is it working now

Comment: hi there problem is header component allowed to add the matierl library again create another component  slidebar not working

Comment: U figured it out?

Comment: how to figured our sir

Comment: github.com/kobin11/angular-project  here is link

Comment: Can you share a stacblitz link?

Comment: i share the gitbub link above